# Issue with Maven war Plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I am using maven to package my war file. I have some dependencies with provided as scope. When i do a maven clean install, the war is created successfully, but the transitive dependencies of the jars with scope as provided are included in my lib directory. Is there any way to remove them ?

Example scenario: Below is one of my dependency in pom

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

this one is including the jar activation-1.1.jar. Also the dependency tree for resteasy-jaxrs is like below.

```
[INFO] +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxrs:jar:2.3.6.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.resteasy:jaxrs-api:jar:2.3.6.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- javax.annotation:jsr250-api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.1.2:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.1.2:provided
[INFO] |  \- net.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0:compile
```

Comment: Can you show us your dependencies?

Comment: @Christian I added the dependency in the question

Comment: Can you post your full pom?

Comment: Is it possible that you've set the scope after your first maven install? It's possible that maven keeps some dependencies. You should try a Maven-> Update Dependencies and check the "Force updates" box.

Comment: I think it is not clear what you want. can you clearify your question?

Comment: @Jens He wants to remove the sub-dependencies from the resteasy-dependency so that they are also provided

Comment: Did you try excluding javax.activation using [maven exclusion](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html)

Comment: @mohit This dependency needs that sub-dependency. So he can't just exclude it. He could exclude it but then he has to addthe dependency manually and set the scope.

Comment: I assume you have several other dependencies which could of course use the dependency as transitive which means you need to check the whole dependency:tree...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to create a `<dependencyManagement>` tag and put the sub-dependency inside and set the scope to provided:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

That way the scope of your transitive-dependency is overwritten:

```
[INFO] |  +- javax.annotation:jsr250-api:jar:1.0:provided (scope managed from compile)
[INFO] |  +- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:provided (scope managed from compile)
```

Be sure to do a `Maven-> Update Project` and check the `Force Update` checkbox before checking the `dependency:tree`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Its working fine. Can you please tell me why the exclusion with the wild card character * is not working in my scenario?

Comment: I don't know what you've tried. But you could exclude it and create a dependency with the provided-scope for sure. But that would be much more work, because this dependency is maybe also nested in other dependencies. With the dependencyManagement you only need to set the scope once.

Comment: Actually what i tried is like below

 <dependency>
     
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
         <exclusions>
         <exclusion>                  
           <artifactid>*</artifactid>
         <groupid>*</groupid>
       <exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

Comment: Ah. That's because transitive-dependencies(your sub-dependencies) override the explicitly set scope of the "main" dependency.

Comment: sorry modified the comment

Comment: I don't know. I've never tried that. But I would not do that. Because that way you have to set every dependency by yourself and manage it by yourself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92826/discussion-between-robin-and-christian).

Answer (score 0):

The above mentioned solution is not possible in case i have so many transitive dependencies coming in my lib. Finally got the maven exclusion which is working fine.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                    <groupId>*</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: This does simply make not sense, cause [provided scope is non transitive](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) which a provided scope will not introduce transitive dependencies.